# Asymptotic formula for twice iterated factorial $(n!)!$

Tags: number-theory, analysis, asymptotics, factorial, lambert-w

Being familiar with [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for factorial:
$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n,\quad\color{gray}{n\to\infty}$$
I naïvely assumed that for twice iterated factorial we can simply substitute the right-hand side into itself and write
$$(n!)!\,\stackrel{\color{red}{\small\text{wrong}}}\sim\,\sqrt{2\pi \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n}e\right)^{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n},$$
but, as it turns out, I was wrong. Actually, it grows faster than that:
$$(n!)!\,\succ\,\sqrt{2\pi \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n}e\right)^{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n}.$$

---

Can we express the correct [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) growth rate of twice iterated factorial $(n!)!$ using only elementary functions and, possibly, also their inverses, such as the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

---

*Update:* Apparently, the same issue arises for simpler functions like $2^{n!}$. If we simply substitute Stirling's formula for the exponent $n!$, we will get an incorrect asymptotic.

Comment: You can use a bound on each side, but they won't agree with one another in the limit. The problem is that if the exponent behaves as $n^k$ then you need to resolve the relative error of the inside of the parentheses down to $n^{-k}$ in order to have bounded relative error overall...and in this case the exponent grows faster than any polynomial. So no finite number of Stirling series terms will get you a correct asymptotic expansion.

Comment: This answer about inverse factorial might be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/461207/19661

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587792/815585

Comment: @Ian Is your argument a heuristic, or it can be made rigorous? Does it apply only to a truncated Stirling series, or any combinations of elementary functions?

Comment: What I said is only for trying to get an asymptotic by taking a Stirling series expression and plug it into itself. No idea about other possibilities.